# Adding video files in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone. I need sample code for how to add video files in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Include the media player framework then do this:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/movie.mov"]]; // this can be an NSURL to a file in your bundle
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mediaPlayer];
 mediaPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [mediaPlayer release];
```

there are notifications and callbacks, but this is the basics.

Answer (score -1):

you can find basically all the things you need here --> http://pdfcast.org/pdf/the-objective-c-programming-language ... download the pdf... enjoy!